# Looking for critique of my reader/writer implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, c++11, locking

i implemented the readers/writers problem in c++11… I'd like to know what's wrong with it, because these kinds of things are difficult to predict on my own.

- Shared database:

  - Readers can access database when no writers
  - Writers can access database when no readers or writers
  - Only one thread manipulates state variables at a time

the example has 3 readers and 1 writer, but also use 2 or more writer....

Code:

```
class ReadersWriters {
private:
    int AR; // number of active readers
    int WR; // number of waiting readers
    int AW; // number of active writers
    int WW; // number of waiting writers
    mutex lock;
    mutex m;
    condition_variable okToRead;
    condition_variable okToWrite;

    int data_base_variable;

public:
    ReadersWriters() : AR(0), WR(0), AW(0), WW(0), data_base_variable(0) {}

    void read_lock() {
        unique_lock<mutex> l(lock);

        WR++; // no writers exist
        // is it safe to read?
        okToRead.wait(l, [this](){ return WW == 0; });
        okToRead.wait(l, [this](){ return AW == 0; });
        WR--; // no longer waiting

        AR++;  // now we are active
    }

    void read_unlock() {
        unique_lock<mutex> l(lock);

        AR--; // no longer active

        if (AR == 0 && WW > 0) { // no other active readers
            okToWrite.notify_one(); // wake up one writer
        }
    }

    void write_lock() {
        unique_lock<mutex> l(lock);

        WW++; // no active user exist
        // is it safe to write?
        okToWrite.wait(l, [this](){ return AR == 0; });
        okToWrite.wait(l, [this](){ return AW == 0; });
        WW--; // no longer waiting

        AW++; // no we are active
    }
    void write_unlock() {
        unique_lock<mutex> l(lock);

        AW--; // no longer active

        if (WW > 0) { // give priority to writers
            okToWrite.notify_one(); // wake up one writer
        }
        else if (WR > 0) { // otherwize, wake reader
            okToRead.notify_all(); // wake all readers
        }
    }

    void data_base_thread_write(unsigned int thread_id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            write_lock();

            data_base_variable++;
            m.lock();
            cout << "data_base_thread: " << thread_id << "...write: " << data_base_variable << endl;
            m.unlock();
            write_unlock();

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }

    void data_base_thread_read(unsigned int thread_id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            read_lock();

            m.lock();
            cout << "data_base_thread: " << thread_id << "...read: " << data_base_variable << endl;
            m.unlock();

            read_unlock();

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    ReadersWriters rw;

    thread w1(&ReadersWriters::data_base_thread_write, &rw, 0);
    thread r1(&ReadersWriters::data_base_thread_read, &rw, 1);
    thread r2(&ReadersWriters::data_base_thread_read, &rw, 2);
    thread r3(&ReadersWriters::data_base_thread_read, &rw, 3);

    w1.join();
    r1.join();
    r2.join();
    r3.join();

    cout << "\nThreads successfully completed..." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Give me feedback for the code.".... sounds like you should have put this on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: why cant i ask it here since its a design question?

Comment: This question is on topic as it is also asking how to interoperate with the C++11 mutex API.  You just have to read a little deeper to realize that.  The only "crime" committed here was the unfortunate wording of the opening sentence in the question, triggering the off-topic response.  I have voted to reopen and urge others to do the same.  At the end of the day, SO should be useful.  And it is not useful to chase this question to a sister site.  My response contains information that will be helpful to a great many C++ coders on SO.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Sorry, but I don't see any other question here but "please give me some feedback". If you think this can be edited into a proper question, do so. I don't see the question, so another 5 close-voters would come by and close it, even if it is reopen. As it stands the close seems totally justified for now.

Comment: @HowardHinnant And looking at your answer, this is totally a code review one.

Comment: @Gerald:  I've edited your question to be consistent with the apparently on-topic question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21561155/576911  .  If for any reason you do not want these edits, please let me know and I will undo them.

Answer (score 1):

Feedback:

`1`.  It is missing all necessary #includes.

`2`. It presumes a `using namespace std`, which is bad style in declarations, as that pollutes all of your clients with namespace std.

`3`. The release of your locks is not exception safe:

```
write_lock();

data_base_variable++;
m.lock();
cout << "data_base_thread: " << thread_id << "...write: " << data_base_variable << endl;
m.unlock();           // leaked if an exception is thrown after m.lock()
write_unlock();       // leaked if an exception is thrown after write_lock()
```

`4`.  The `m.lock()` wrapping of `cout` in `data_base_thread_write` is really unnecessary since `write_lock()` should already be providing exclusive access.  However I understand that this is just a demo.

`5`.  I *think* I see a bug in the read/write logic:

```
step   1     2     3    4     5    6
WR     0     1     1    1     0    0
AR     0     0     0    0     1    1
WW     0     0     1    1     1    0
AW     1     1     1    0     0    1
```

In step 1, thread 1 has the write lock.

In step 2, thread 2 attempts to acquire a read lock, increments `WR`, and blocks on the second `okToRead`, waiting for `AW == 0`.

In step 3, thread 3 attempts to acquire a write lock, increments `WW`, and blocks on the second `okToWrite`, waiting for `AW == 0`.

In step 4, thread 1 releases, the write lock by decrementing `AW` to 0, and signals `okToWrite`.

In step 5, thread 2, despite not being signaled, is awoken *spuriously*, notes that `AW == 0`, and grabs the read lock by setting `WR` to 0 and `AR` to 1.

In step 6, thread 3 receives the signal, notes that `AW == 0`, and grabs the write lock by setting `WW` to 0 and `AW` to 1.

In step 6, both thread 2 owns the read lock and thread 3 owns the write lock (simultaneously).

`6`.  The class `ReadersWriters` has two functions:

1. It implements a read/write mutex.
2. It implements tasks for threads to execute.

A better design would take advantage of the mutex/lock framework established in C++11:

Create a `ReaderWriter` mutex with members:

```
// unique ownership
void lock();      // write_lock
void unlock();    // write_unlock
// shared ownership
lock_shared();    // read_lock
unlock_shared();  // read_unlock
```

The first two names, `lock` and `unlock` are purposefully the same names as those used by the C++11 mutex types.  Just doing this much allows you to do things like:

```
std::lock_guard<ReaderWriter>  lk1(mut);
// ...
std::unique_lock<ReaderWriter> lk2(mut);
// ...
std::condition_variable_any cv;
cv.wait(lk2);  // wait using the write lock
```

And if you add:

```
void try_lock();
```

Then you can also:

```
std::lock(lk2, <any other std or non-std locks>);  // lock multiple locks
```

The `lock_shared` and `unlock_shared` names are chosen because of the `std::shared_lock<T>` type currently in the C++1y (we hope y is 4) working draft.  It is documented in [N3659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3659.html).
And then you can say things like:

```
std::shared_lock<ReaderWriter> lk3(mut);   // read_lock
std::condition_variable_any cv;
cv.wait(lk3);  // wait using the read lock
```

I.e. By just creating a stand-alone `ReaderWriter` mutex type, with very carefully chosen names for the member functions, you get interoperability with the std-defined locks, `condition_variable_any`, and locking algorithms.

See [N2406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#shared_mutex) for a more in-depth rationale of this framework.

Comment: Hi howard, thanks for your feedback, i tried to implement the lock/unlock by myself in order to understand the concept. how did you create the table in 5? i modified my code a bit...i dont know how to repaste code in here...so i uploaded my code to: [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1e74d76f5fa6341) ... does it fix the issue you saw?

Comment: I generated the table just by inspection of the source code.  I was not able to demonstrate that state by an experiment.  Yes, I believe your modification addresses the problem.  I now think you are tantalizingly close to having reinvented Alexander Terekhov's algorithm 8a, which is a pretty impressive feat. :-)

Comment: howard: no need to reinvent :) does the shared_lock come with some overhead compared to using the mutex direclty: mutex.lock() ... mutex.unlock() ?

Comment: @Gerald:  `shared_lock` contains a possibly null pointer to the mutex, and a bool indicating whether the `shared_lock` owns the lock on the mutex or not.  There is an invariant that if the bool is true, then the pointer is non-null (points to a valid and share-locked mutex).  The only overhead is that `~shared_lock()` will first check that the bool is true before calling `unlock_shared()`.  Imho this overhead is inconsequential.  This is the exact same overhead as `unique_lock`.