# Looking for critique of my thread safe, lock-free queue implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue, lock-free

So, I've written a queue, after a bit of research.  It uses a fixed-size buffer, so it's a circular queue.  It has to be thread-safe, and I've tried to make it lock-free.  I'd like to know what's wrong with it, because these kinds of things are difficult to predict on my own.

Here's the header:

```
template <class T>
class LockFreeQueue
{
public:
    LockFreeQueue(uint buffersize) : buffer(NULL), ifront1(0), ifront2(0), iback1(0), iback2(0), size(buffersize) { buffer = new atomic <T>[buffersize]; }
    ~LockFreeQueue(void) { if (buffer) delete[] buffer; }

    bool pop(T* output);
    bool push(T input);

private:
    uint incr(const uint val)
        {return (val + 1) % size;}

    atomic <T>* buffer;
    atomic <uint> ifront1, ifront2, iback1, iback2;
    uint size;
};
```

And here's the implementation:

```
template <class T>
bool LockFreeQueue<T>::pop(T* output)
{
    while (true)
    {
        /* Fetch ifront and store it in i. */
        uint i = ifront1;

        /* If ifront == iback, the queue is empty. */
        if (i == iback2)
            return false;

        /* If i still equals ifront, increment ifront, */
        /* Incrememnting ifront1 notifies pop() that it can read the next element. */
        if (ifront1.compare_exchange_weak(i, incr(i)))
        {
            /* then fetch the output. */
            *output = buffer[i];
            /* Incrememnting ifront2 notifies push() that it's safe to write. */
            ++ifront2;
            return true;
        }

        /* If i no longer equals ifront, we loop around and try again. */
    }
}

template <class T>
bool LockFreeQueue<T>::push(T input)
{
    while (true)
    {
        /* Fetch iback and store it in i. */
        uint i = iback1;

        /* If ifront == (iback +1), the queue is full. */
        if (ifront2 == incr(i))
            return false;

        /* If i still equals iback, increment iback, */
        /* Incrememnting iback1 notifies push() that it can write a new element. */
        if (iback1.compare_exchange_weak(i, incr(i)))
        {
            /* then store the input. */
            buffer[i] = input;
            /* Incrementing iback2 notifies pop() that it's safe to read. */
            ++iback2;
            return true;
        }

        /* If i no longer equals iback, we loop around and try again. */
    }
}
```

EDIT:  I made some major modifications to the code, based on comments (Thanks KillianDS and n.m.!).  Most importantly, ifront and iback are now ifront1, ifront2, iback1, and iback2.   push() will now increment iback1, notifying other pushing threads that they can safely write to the next element (as long as it's not full), write the element, then increment iback2.  iback2 is all that gets checked by pop().  pop() does the same thing, but with the ifrontn indices.

Now, once again, I fall into the trap of "this SHOULD work...", but I don't know anything about formal proofs or anything like that.  At least this time, I can't think of a potential way that it could fail.  Any advice is appreciated, except for "stop trying to write lock-free code".

Comment: A concurrent container doensn't *have* a size, nor has it "full" or "empty" states. Those are meaningless.

Comment: @KerrekSB: A circular buffer *does* have a size, and they are often used as concurrent containers, so ...

Comment: A side note. `if (ifront == iback) return true; else return false;` in `isEmpty()` should just be `return ifront == iback;` same in `isFull()`. Avoid avoid extra if-else.

Comment: @concept3d Its not necessarily thread safe, it may not have to be...It certainly doesn't follow the rule of 3, probably should set the buffer to NULL, copy constructor and assignment, ect

Comment: @ZanLynx It makes no sense for the size and "emptiness" to be part of the public interface if other threads can concurrently change that state.

Comment: To me, it seems your concerns are justified: the `compare_and_exchange` in `push` both notifies writers that the element may not be written to any more and readers that the element can *now* be read from. There's no guarantee the atomic write to `buffer[i]` occurs before the read in the first scenario.

Comment: In the same line with @murrekatt's code, `incr` can be simplified to `return (val+1)%size`. It does not change anything, but less code is easier to grasp in concurrency.

Comment: I do not think comparison atomicx == atomicy is atomic (speaking of isEmpty() and isFull())

Comment: It seems to me that if the writer is quick enough it can overwrite the node after you've incremented the pointer and before you've fetched the data from the node, in pop()

Comment: I've removed isEmpty() and isFull() from the interface.  I didn't actually have any plans that required them, I just figured that they would be useful maybe, but if they cause problems then it's best if they go away.

Comment: Have a read: http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=210604448&siteSectionName=parallel

Comment: "which gives thread B time" -- how much time? Is it enough to do what it needs to do? Unless you can fill in the numbers, this is not a valid line of reasoning. Stick to "X happens before Y".

Comment: If one statement is executed after another on thread B, with no pauses in between statements, then it works.  If both threads are running on the same processor, the operating system may choose to execute something else in between those two statements.  Therein lies the potential for errors.

Comment: I think you can successfully implements a lock-free circular buffer if you use *two* indices for back and front (two of each). At the push side you advance iback1, push, then advance iback2. The pop side only looks at iback2.

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to approach a lock free data structure is to write a semi formal proof that your design works in pseudo code.  You shouldn't be asking "is this lock free code thread safe", but rather "does my proof that this lock free code is thread safe have any errors?"

Only after you have a formal proof that a pseudo code design works do you try to implement it.  Often this brings to light issues like garbage collection that have to be handled carefully.

Your code should be the formal proof and pseudo code in comments, with the relatively unimportant implementation interspersed within.

Verifying your code is correct then consists of understanding the pseudo code, checking the proof, then checking for failure for your code to map to your pseudo code and proof.

Directly taking code and trying to check that it is lock free is impractical.  The proof is the important thing in correctly designing this kind of thing, the actual code is secondary, as the proof is the hard part.

And *after* and *while* you have done all of the above, and have other people validate it, you have to put your code through practical tests to see if you have a blind spot and there is a hole, or don't understand your concurrency primitives, or if your concurrency primitives have bugs in them.

If you aren't interested in writing semi formal proofs to design your code, you shouldn't be hand rolling lock free algorithms and data structures and putting them into place in production code.

Determining if a pile of code "is thread safe" is putting all of the work load on other people.  You need to have an argument why your code "is thread safe" arranged in such a way that it is as easy as possible for others to find holes in it.  If your argument why your code "is thread safe" is arranged in ways that makes it harder to find holes, your code cannot be presumed to be thread safe, even if nobody can spot a hole in your code.

The code you posted above is a mess.  It contains commented out code, no formal invariants, no proofs that the lines, no strong description of why it is thread safe, and in general does not put forward an attempt to show itself as thread safe in a way that makes it easy to spot flaws.  As such, no reasonable reader will consider the code thread safe, even if they cannot find any errors in it.

Comment: -1 This is an opinion based scolding, when the asker simply asked a straight-forward question - which admittedly he should not have asked without more work on his part.

Comment: @Zak it also tells him how to write a thread safe algorithm.  Start with the pseudo code and the proof.  Even if nobody here could find an error in his code, the lack of proof means that the code cannot be considered reliably thread safe.  (Note a proof is not sufficient: rather necessary).

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not thread safe - consider the following sequence if events:

1. First thread completes `if (ifront.compare_exchange_weak(i, incr(i)))` in `pop` and goes to sleep by scheduler.
2. Second thread calls push `size` times (just enough to make ifront be equal to value of `i` in the first thread).
3. First thread wakes.

In this case pop `buffer[i]` will contain the last pushed value, which is wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to notify the scheduler to not put the thread to sleep between compare_exchange and buffer[i]'s read/write?

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach No, unless you are on some real-time OS with kernel-level critical section (but that will make your code non-lock-free). I wonder why do you need lock-free queue at all. If just for self-education, than it's ok, but do not ever use self-written lock-free code in production code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues when considering wrap-around but I think the main issue of your code is that it may pop invalid values from the buffer.

Consider this:

ifront = iback = 0

Push gets called and CAS increases the value of iback 0 -> 1. However the thread now get's stalled before buffer[0] is assigned.

ifront = 0, iback = 1

Pop is now called. CAS increases ifront 1 -> 1 and buffer[0] is read before it's assigned.

A stale or invalid value is popped.

PS. Some researches therefore have asked for a DCAS or TCAS (Di and Tri CAS).

Comment: A potential way forward is implementing a spin lock.